# Windows 10 on USB

Tags: windows-10, uefi, iso-image

I've been trying to install Windows 10 onto an external SSD [this tutorial](https://www.partition-tool.com/resource/windows-10-partition-manager/install-windows-10-on-external-hard-drive.html) as well as ISO to USB and neither have worked. For the tutorial, the files on the drive are what you'd expect to see on a Windows drive (Users, Program Files(x86), etc) but when I use ISO to USB and check the "make bootable" option, all I see is an uncompressed version of the ISO file.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://www.onmsft.com/news/create-windows-go-usb-drive-running-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

As a removeable system on USB, Windows To Go may meet your demand.

Windows To Go is a feature in Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 10 Education that enables the creation of a Windows To Go workspace that can be booted from a USB-connected external drive on PCs.

How to Create a Windows To Go USB Drive

https://www.howtogeek.com/196817/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive-without-the-enterprise-edition/